# Angry org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleMissingPluginsException in Step : JmsOutput Why?

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde

I made a `Transform` to send `JMS Produce` to `ActiveMQ`.

but during executing the transform via my Java Client Application including `PDI` Jars.

I faced this Error :

```
SEVERE: null
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleMissingPluginsException:
Missing plugins found while loading a transformation


Step : JmsOutput
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.loadXML(TransMeta.java:2840)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2676)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2628)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2605)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2585)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2550)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2513)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

so any Help please?

Comment: Is that transformation works inside PDI?

Comment: Yes works fine inside PDI, but as i explained that i'm running it via command line using PDI Jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the infocenter.pentaho.com:

```
Note: Place JMS Library jars for the ConnectionFactory and other supporting classes in the .../data-integration/plugins/pdi-jms-plugin/lib directory.
```

Comment: Thank you, i place Jars of JMS inside Class-Path but nothing solved. Can you explain more steps of your answer ?

Comment: i got more details :
`Unable to load class for step/plugin with id [JmsOutput]. Check if the plugin is
 available in the plugins subdirectory of the Kettle distribution.`

Comment: Thank you it has been solved by adding the `plugins` folder that contain `JMS` library in the root path of the application, but i face another something :D `Exception in thread "Thread-8" com.pentaho.commons.dsc.f: license missing, invalid, or expired` :D